# Eclipse IDE/Jpasskit not able to configure

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, wallet, passkit

newly started using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers for one of my new project i have to configure [Jpasskit](https://github.com/drallgood/jpasskit) for my iphone project. i created new test.java file.

eclipse project explorer:

[image]

```
public static void main(String [ ] args)
{

    String appleWWDRCA = "passbook/AppleWWDRCA.pem"; // this is apple's developer relation cert
    String privateKeyPath = "./privateKey.p12"; // the private key you exported from keychain
    String privateKeyPassword = "password"; // the password you used to export
    try {

    PKSigningInformation pkSigningInformation = PKSigningUtil.
            loadSigningInformationFromPKCS12FileAndIntermediateCertificateFile(
            privateKeyPath, privateKeyPassword, appleWWDRCA);

    PKPass pass = new PKPass();
    pass.setPassTypeIdentifier("pass.com.yourdomain.type");
    pass.setAuthenticationToken("vxwxd7J8AlNNFPS8k0a0FfUFtq0ewzFdc");
    pass.setSerialNumber("12345678000");
    pass.setTeamIdentifier("abcdefg"); // replace this with your team ID
    pass.setOrganizationName("your org");
    pass.setDescription("some description");
    pass.setLogoText("some logo text");

    PKBarcode barcode = new PKBarcode();
    barcode.setFormat(PKBarcodeFormat.PKBarcodeFormatPDF417);
    barcode.setMessageEncoding(Charset.forName("iso-8859-1"));
    barcode.setMessage("123456789");
    pass.setBarcode(barcode);

    PKGenericPass generic = new PKGenericPass();
    List<PKField> primaryFields = new ArrayList<PKField>();
    PKField member = new PKField();
    member.setKey("mykey"); // some unique key for primary field
    member.setValue("myvalue"); // some value
    primaryFields.add(member);
    generic.setPrimaryFields(primaryFields);
    pass.setGeneric(generic);

    PKLocation location = new PKLocation();
    location.setLatitude(37.33182); // replace with some lat
    location.setLongitude(-122.03118); // replace with some long
    List<PKLocation> locations = new ArrayList<PKLocation>();
    locations.add(location);
    pass.setLocations(locations);

    if (pass.isValid()) {
        String pathToTemplateDirectory = "./mypass.raw"; // replace with your folder with the icons
        byte[] passZipAsByteArray = PKSigningUtil.
                createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive(pass, pathToTemplateDirectory, pkSigningInformation);

        String outputFile = "./mypass.pkpass"; // change the name of the pass
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(passZipAsByteArray);
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        System.out.println("Done!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("the pass is NOT Valid man!!!");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("failed!");
}
}
```

When ever im running this code as application im getting this error.
[image]

i dont know what im doing wrong?

im not sure i imported project right ..
or classpth issue.
or maybe something wrong in my sample calss.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ant installed? Is ANT_HOME, CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME set? Is JAVA_HOME same as jdk used by your project?

Comment: no doesn't install with eclipse ? do i have install separately